# Magento: improving default search engine

Tags: magento

So, I changed the default Magento search engine slightly, and it works close to how I want it. (i.e. `OR` term search to `AND`). However, there is one more thing that I'd like to implement. When a person searches for a series of terms, like `Green Apple A`, I'd like the product Green Apple A to show up first. Right now, with the `AND` operator, the results are in the order they were pulled from the DB. So, the Green Apple A might show up in anywhere.

Here is the function that prepares the results.. It is a bit complicated for me, and I'm wondering if there's an easy way to "append" a search result that looks for the specific sequence of the inputted terms and concatenates the results, giving this priority, so it shows up first.

(Sorry for the long code. I typically don't like posting large amount of code)

From `Fulltext.php` in `/stores/my_website/app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource`

```
public function prepareResult($object, $queryText, $query)
{

    $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
    if (!$query->getIsProcessed()) {
        $searchType = $object->getSearchType($query->getStoreId());

        $preparedTerms = Mage::getResourceHelper('catalogsearch')
            ->prepareTerms($queryText, $query->getMaxQueryWords());

        $bind = array();
        $like = array();
        $likeCond  = '';
        if ($searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_LIKE
            || $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_COMBINE
        ) {
            $helper = Mage::getResourceHelper('core');
            $words = Mage::helper('core/string')->splitWords($queryText, true, $query->getMaxQueryWords());
            foreach ($words as $word) {
                $like[] = $helper->getCILike('s.data_index', $word, array('position' => 'any'));
            }
            if ($like) {
                $likeCond = '(' . join(' AND ', $like) . ')';
            }
        }
        $mainTableAlias = 's';
        $fields = array(
            'query_id' => new Zend_Db_Expr($query->getId()),
            'product_id',
        );
        $select = $adapter->select()
            ->from(array($mainTableAlias => $this->getMainTable()), $fields)
            ->joinInner(array('e' => $this->getTable('catalog/product')),
                'e.entity_id = s.product_id',
                array())
            ->where($mainTableAlias.'.store_id = ?', (int)$query->getStoreId());

        if ($searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_FULLTEXT
            || $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_COMBINE
        ) {
            $bind[':query'] = implode(' ', $preparedTerms[0]);
            $where = Mage::getResourceHelper('catalogsearch')
                ->chooseFulltext($this->getMainTable(), $mainTableAlias, $select);
        }

        if ($likeCond != '' && $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_COMBINE) {
                $where .= ($where ? ' AND ' : '') . $likeCond;
        } elseif ($likeCond != '' && $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_LIKE) {
            $select->columns(array('relevance'  => new Zend_Db_Expr(0)));
            $where = $likeCond;
        }

        if ($where != '') {
            $select->where($where);
        }

        $sql = $adapter->insertFromSelect($select,
            $this->getTable('catalogsearch/result'),
            array(),
            Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INSERT_ON_DUPLICATE);
        $adapter->query($sql, $bind);

        $query->setIsProcessed(1);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this free extension for default search

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/12202/s/enhanced-default-search-9697